# Extract video without audio ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, terminal, video-streaming, video-processing

I am trying to change the resolution to 640x480 and extract a video segment without the audio stream using ffmpeg. I am not sure if this command is correct:

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -vf scale=640:480 -ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:20 -an output.avi
```

Comment: You're trying to reduce *quality*, or are you trying to set the *frame size*?  In any case, is it not working for you?  Why are you trying to map `0:a`?  `-an` does what you want to drop the audio.

Comment: @Brad I am trying to change the size from 1920x1080 to 640x480. I was trying to use map to filter the video from the 10 sec to 20 sec mark, because it seems that I cannot use `copy` with `-vf`

Comment: Yeah, you can't use copy because that would just copy over the bitstream.  Drop your `-map 0` and `-map -0:a`, and it should work for you.

Comment: @Brad I see, I have edited the cmd, would this be correct?

Comment: Try it and see.  :-)

Comment: @Brad Yes, this works although the output is very pixelated. I assume that's because it's 640p. But, my original command also worked and gave a similar output. I am not sure I get what the difference is..

Comment: For AVI output, ffmpeg defaults to mpeg4 encoder at 200 kbps.  Add `-b:v 1500k` for better quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your use of the `-an` flag is the right thing to do here.

Refer to https://superuser.com/questions/268985/remove-audio-from-video-file-with-ffmpeg#268986

Also, If I'm not mistaken, what you are producing is 480p, not 640p. If you really want 640p, you'd use scale=852:639 or scale=856:642, since you're using a 4:3 aspect ratio

Comment: Actually, I just want to change the `resolution` to `640x480`, is that different from 640p?

Comment: Ah yeah, that's just 480p. the 480p comes from the "vertical lines" on the screen, coming all the way from the analog video era.

Comment: I see, so it's correct to use `scale heightxwidth` right if I want to change the resolution?

Comment: yes, what you have is correct. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: The syntax is `scale=width:height`.